# Override a CSS variable and assign it to another variable doesn't take effect (var chain)

Tags: css, chain, css-variables

Sorry if the title is a little bit confusing but i didn't know how to describe it more understandable in english.

Does someone know why the first div does not have a red border. I would assume that the **--secondary** variable becomes overriden by child and would take effect on every other variable that assigns this variable?!

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/wJQVRO
```

**EDIT**
Dont ask me why plunker and codepen dont support @apply but thats nearly the use case i need

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJQVRO/

```
  body {
    --primarycolor: {
      border: 2px solid var(--secondary);
    };

    --secondary: blue;
    border:2px solid var(--secondary);
    padding:5px;
  }

  div {
    --secondary: red;
    @apply(--primarycolor);
    padding:5px;
  }

  p {
    --secondary: black;
    @apply(--primarycolor);
    padding:5px;
  }
```

In my polymer environment the @apply works, but thats not the problem, sorry for that..couldn't determine why codepen and plunker don't support it?! Anyway the problem i'm trying to explain is that the div and p element will both have a blue border and not like expected a red and a black border. Assume that the --primarycolor set is a great set of properties, it then would be a big effort to me if that work like expected.

Comment: _"Does someone know why the first div does not have a red border"_ I believe  that is because `--secondary` is already applied to your `--primarycolor` in `body` and by the time `--primary-cololr` reach your div definition it is `border: 2px solid blue` . I'm guessing you will need to change how you apply the border.

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning the `--secondary` color to `red`, but assigning the `div` border color a value of `--primarycolor` which is `blue` stated in the `body`

```
div {
    --secondary: red; // change this to --primarycolor: red;
    color: var(--primarycolor);
    border:2px solid var(--primarycolor); // or change this to var(--secondary)
    padding:5px;
  }
```

so either change the border assignment to `var(--secondary)` or change to --`primarycolor: red` instead of the `--secondary: red`

Comment: thanks but thats not what i'm looking for...there is some misunderstanding. I edited my post.